# Lazy-load imports from barrel file in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I'm using React and have a file tree like this:

```
src/
  common/
    common-comp1/
      common-comp1.js
      common-comp1.test.js
      index.js
    common-comp2/
      common-comp2.js
      common-comp2.test.js
      index.js
    index.js
  app/
    app-comp1/
      app-comp1.js
      app-comp1.test.js
      index.js
    app-comp2/
      app-comp2.js
      app-comp2.test.js
      index.js
    index.js
```

All of the index.js files are barrel files that `export * from '...';`.  I have path aliases set up so that I can `import CommonComp1 from 'common';` in `src/app/app-comp1/app-comp1.js`.

Unfortunately, this loads/transforms the code from `src/common/common-comp2/*` as well, even though `app-comp1.js` doesn't import it.  This is fine when I build the app with webpack, because I need everything to be imported and transformed anyway.

However, with tests, with some 350 components, this makes running a single test suite very slow on startup.  I only want to import/transform the files necessary to run the tests.  Is there a way to lazy-load every export/import?  I thought maybe I could do this by mocking my barrel files and exporting a `Proxy` that only requires/memoizes components when they are imported directly, by calling `jest.requireActual()`.  I started to do this, but then realized I'd have to parse the entire file tree for import and export names, which sounds tedious.  (At least I think I would have to do this.)

I thought I might also try proxying `require()` itself (I attempted this several weeks ago for a different issue), but iirc, it is a constant or declared non-configurable/non-writable.

Thoughts?

Comment: I mean, I'd have to set up a whole project.  Is that what you want?  I can do it after work.

Comment: Haha thanks.  I was *just* working on it.  Too tired after work yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock the barrel file in your test using the module factory parameter, and set only the exports you want.

if common-comp1.js exports as default do it like this:

app-comp1.test.js:

```
jest.mock('common',()=>{
  const CommonComp1 = jest.requireActual('common/common-comp1').default;
  return {__esModule: true, CommonComp1}
})
```

if common-comp1.js exports are named then do it like this:

app-comp1.test.js:

```
jest.mock('common',()=>{
  const allNamedExports = jest.requireActual('common/common-comp1');
  return {__esModule: true, ...allNamedExports}
})
```

for a more automated version you could have `__mocks__/index.js` files generated by a script.

that script would go through each index.js file import it, get the name of the exports and put them in a module.exports object getter.

Like this:

`__mocks__/common.js`:

```
module.exports={
    get CommonComp1() { 
        return jest.requireActual('../common/common-comp1').CommonComp1;
    }
    get OtherExportFromCommonComp1() { 
        return jest.requireActual('../common/common-comp1').OtherExportFromCommonComp1;
    }
    get CommonComp2() { 
        return jest.requireActual('../common/common-comp2').CommonComp2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Five questions:  1) How would this work for barrel files that import barrel files?  2) Is it possible to generate these in-memory once at the beginning of a test run (and would that defeat the entire performance boost)?  3) I use typescript, and sometimes I only import an interface/type from a file.  How hard would it be to detect these cases?  4) What about cases where I *do* want to mock an import?  5) Want to write this fancy script for me?  

Comment: 1) you basically would not care - you import everything from your barrel file, it does not matter if in the end it imports from another one. Then you can also generate the mock for the inner barrel files, in case those are also directly used in the code. 2) I guess that would defeat the purpose 3) Not sure about this one 4) I think you would be able to use the mock factory parameter to override the manual mocks 5) sorry that would take me a considerable amount of time and depend on some of your specifics as well